# getOldLeadSelectionPath returns null if collapsing its parent

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a Problem with the JTree listener Event for selection changes. The problem is that:
- First I select an item in the tree under an other item (e. g. Node A -> Node B (selected))
--> Old selection is null, new Selection is [Node A, Node B]
- Than I collapse the parent node of this node (e. g. collapse all children of Node A)
--> Old selection is null(!) and new Selection is Node A

Why the event returns a null selection for the old item? Is it a bug?

Thanks for reply!

Comment: post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable caused a.m. issue with selection in JTree, could be better than shouting here

Comment: looks like a behaviour change:  in 6 - two selection events, first with newLead == null, second with oldLead == null; in 7: one selection event, with oldLead == null. Both are weird, but the 6ish at least allows to be notified ... Personally, would say it's a bug - a nasty workaround would be to keep track of the old lead in your listener

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionEvent.html#oldLeadSelectionPath) it can be null.

At First selection old path always null.

Then you collapse your node and your tree hasn't path to last node(for you in collapsed Node A) because of you again get null.

Comment: 1) I point in doc to a variable, not for a method, and it can be null. 2)as recommended by @kleopatra you can track old with the own listener. 3) You can try to extend `JTree` with your implementation.